# Android Studio won't start on Linux - complaining about libcups

Tags: linux, android-studio

My system is Gentoo Linux 64bit, and I have get the latest Android Studio for Linux. When I try to start it, I got this [error message](http://bpaste.net/show/152275/). Looking through the message, it looks like the reason is that I do not have the `libcups.so` library.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/icedtea-bin-7.2.4.3/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so: libcups.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
```

Indeed, I do not have *cups* installed. But I don't understand why the Studio needs this library. Is there any way I can avoid installing this library and still get the Studio work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't used Android Studio, but I guess Android Studio uses CUPS for printing. Making it not need CUPS would require the removal of the printing code.

Comment: yeah, I know `libcups` is for printing. but what kind of development tool make print a mandatory feature? dumb... :(

Comment: @davidshen84 They probably never thought about users without libcups and thought it was easy to install libcups, in any case. [Gentoo Printing Howto](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/printing-howto.xml).